# Error in testing part of my django poll app

Tags: django

I get the following error in my django poll app. I do not understand what it states, can anyone suggest me what to do? Any solution to this?

```
NameError at / name 'model' is not defined 
Request Method: GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ 
Django Version: 1.8.6 
Exception Type: NameError 
Exception Value:     name 'model' is not defined 
Exception Location: c:\Anaconda-installation\mysite\polls\views.py in ResultView, line 26 
Python Executable:  C:\Anaconda-installation\python.exe 
Python Version: 2.7.10 
Python Path:     ['c:\\Anaconda-installation\\mysite',  
                  'C:\\Anaconda-installation\\python27.zip',  
                  'C:\\Anaconda-installation\\DLLs',  
                  'C:\\Anaconda-installation\\lib',  
                  'C:\\Anaconda-installation\\lib\\plat-win',  
                  'C:\\Anaconda-installation\\lib\\lib-tk',  
                  'C:\\Anaconda-installation',  
                  'c:\\anaconda-installation\\lib\\site-packages\\sphinx-1.3.1-py2.7.egg',  
                  'c:\\anaconda-installation\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-17.1.1-py2.7.egg', 
                  'C:\\Anaconda-installation\\lib\\site-packages',  
                  'C:\\Anaconda-installation\\lib\\site-packages\\cryptography-0.9.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg',  
                  'C:\\Anaconda-installation\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',  
                  'C:\\Anaconda-installation\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',  
                  'C:\\Anaconda-installation\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin'] 
Server time:    Tue, 8 Dec 2015 04:49:21 +0000
```

Comment: The error is shown in the first line: `'model' is not defined`. It means you're trying to call a word called `model` in your `ReseltView` at line 26 and that word `model` has not been defined earlier.

Comment: It would be better if you could find an appropriate title for your post so that others experiencing the same problem may find it through a search engine.

Comment: thank you... @xyres where can i define that i clearly checked everything

Comment: show us the code for `ResultView`